# Make it impossible for users to remove web parts/zones?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

In Sharepoint, is it possible to deny regular users the possibility of removing web parts and/or web part zones? If yes; how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options to deny users from closing/moving a web part are in the 'Advanced' section of the web part's tool pane in sharepoint (Accessed via the 'Modify Shared Web Part' option in the web part's menu).

Alternatively you can modify the permission levels for the site (Site settings > Permissions > Settings > Permission Levels) and remove the 'Add/Remove personal web parts' and 'Update personal web parts' permissions from the levels your users run as.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually found what I needed before I read your answer. Thnx anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be controlled through site roles. By default, the available roles are Full Control, Design, Contribute, Read, and Limited Access.

Users that are not members of Contribute or higher will not be able to remove web parts or web part zones for that site.